# Unbalanced Panel Data Fixed Effects Model with Instruments and Robust or Clustered standard errors

Tags: r, panel-data

I'm an undergraduate with very little experience in R and Econometrics, so forgive me if I mix-up my terms a little bit.

So far, I have gathered an unbalanced panel data set that contains student attainment data from IPEDS and Labor Force stats from American Fact Finder. I'm trying to run a 2SLS model in R and I'm having a rough time.

My question: Is there a way to run a fixed effects model with one instrument and clustered or robust error terms in R? I have been using the `ivreg` function for the 2SLS regressions and that has been working; however, because I have tried to include so many fixed effects with the `factor(x)` command, I keep getting error messages from R when I try to include some of my independent variables. I explored the `plm` package a little bit and I keep getting errors because my panel is unbalanced.

Comment: I would recommend either a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with the errors, or posting on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Not yet specific enough. Agree this is more appropriate in a venue that handles statistical theory questions.